# How to create a valid `Blob` object in jest?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a valid Blob object for one of my test cases in react jest.
I am using `new Blob` to create a Blob but getting an empty Blob object like `Blob {}`.

```js
const myBlob = new Blob([`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/
2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/`], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

console.log(myBlob);
```

What I think there is a native javascript code missing in jest to create a new Blob.
Is there any other way to achieve it. Please let me know. I am new to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/735226
Basically you need a byte array, you cannot just create a Blob from base64.
Or you use the fetch approach like here, which is far simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/735226

Comment: Also to add: Jest is just a library that runs on a specific platform, so every javascript feature that this platform (i.e. nodejs or a browser) implemented is available. It has nothing to do with jest.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/';

const data_bytes = atob(data);

const data_arr = new Array(data_bytes.length).map((_, i) => data_bytes.charCodeAt(i));

const data_barr = new Uint8Array(data_arr);

const myBlob = new Blob([data_barr], { type: 'image/jpeg' });

console.log(myBlob);
```